# c# virtual method inside parent class calls another virtual method which is overridden in child class

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a c# class A which inherits from class B which in turn inherits from class C.

```
Class A : Class B
{}

Class B : Class C
{
    override OnIntialise()
    {
    do something else...
    }
}

Class C
{
    virtual Initialise()
    {
        OnIntialise();
    }
    virtual OnInitialise()
    {
        do something...
    }
}
```

Now when I call a.Initialise(), the program will call the method Initialise() defined inside Class C. Inside Initialise(), will the method OnIntialise() defined in Class C or Class B be invoked?

Comment: _"will the method OnIntialise() defined in Class C or Class B be invoked?"_ -- what happened when you tried it? What didn't you understand about your _observed result_? Why are you asking the entire Stack Overflow community to weigh in on something you could easily just test yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Initialise` method of class `B` will be called in this case as it is being overridden in the child class i.e. class `B`. Had this method been overridden in class `A` then method in class `A` would have got called.

Comment: what if inside the Initialise() method of Class C is this.OnInitialise() ?

Comment: It would be same. You can see the flow by putting breakpoints in you code though.